# How to make an update button work that isn't returning any errors, but not updating the information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

So I am working on a library management system using ASP.NET, C# and SQL Server. I'm also using bootstrap and other styling libraries, if that information is necessary.

On the Book Management page on the admin side, there is an add, update and delete button. The add and delete buttons work perfectly fine, however, the update button does not work at all. As far as I and intellisense can tell, the code is perfectly fine. Also, the code is similar to the one that is used for the add button, save for the SQL query. There isn't even an error that shows up, the page just reloads and no information is updated. Even inserting an incorrect BookID does not do anything or report the nonexistence of the book, just reloads with no change. If it means anything, on all the other pages, the update buttons work without issue. The code for the update function:

```
void updateBook()
{
    try
    {
        int stock = Convert.ToInt32(AllStockTxt.Text.Trim());
        int currentStock = Convert.ToInt32(CrrntStckTxt.Text.Trim());

        if (StockGlobal == stock)
        {

        }

        else
        {
            if (stock < StockGlobal)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Sorry, the Stock value cannot be less than the Issued Books value.')</script>");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                currentStock = stock - IssuedBooksGlobal;
                CrrntStckTxt.Text = "" + currentStock;
            }
        }

        string genre ="";

        foreach (int i in ListBoxGenre.GetSelectedIndices())
        {
            genre = genre + ListBoxGenre.Items[i] + ",";
        }

        genre = genre.Remove(genre.Length - 1);

        string filepath = "~/BookImages/BooksIcon.jpg";
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadBookMgmnt.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (filename == "" || filename == null)
        {
            filename = FilePathGlobal;
        }

        else
        {
            FileUploadBookMgmnt.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("BookImages/" + filename));
            filepath = "~/BookImages/" + filename;
        }

        SqlConnection dbconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStrng);
        if (dbconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            dbconnection.Open();
        }


        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Books SET BookName = @Bookname, Author = @Author, Publisher = @Publisher, Language = @Language, DatePublished = @DatePublished, Genre = @Genre, Edition = @Edition, PageCount = @PageCount, Stock = @Stock, CurrentStock = @CurrentStock, BookImage = @BookImage, BookDescription = @BookDesc WHERE AuthorID = '" + BookIDMgmtTxt.Text.Trim() + "'", dbconnection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookName", BookNameMgmtTxt.Text.Trim());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", DropDownAuthor.SelectedItem.Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publisher", DropDownPublisher.SelectedItem.Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", DropDownLanguage.SelectedItem.Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePublished", PublishDateTxt.Text.Trim());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edition", EditionTxt.Text.Trim());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageCount", PageNumTxt.Text.Trim());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stock", stock.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentStock", currentStock.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookDesc", BookDescTxt.Text.Trim());

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", genre);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookImage", filepath);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbconnection.Close();

        BookInvtryListMgmntGrdView.DataBind();

        Response.Write("<script>alert('Book information updated successfully.')</script>");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
    }
}
```

StockGlobal and IssuedBooksGlobal are public variables that hold the stock and issued books stored in the database to allow to calculate the number of books that are available based on how many books have been issued out.

The click event:

```
protected void UpdateBookMgmtBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBookExists())
    {
        updateBook();
    }

    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('The BookID you have entered does not exist.')</script>");
    }
}
```

The checkBookExists functions just checks that the BookID exists in the database.

The Page Load Event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        fillAuthorPublisherDetails();
       
    }

    BookInvtryListMgmntGrdView.DataBind();
```

fillAuthorPublisherDetails inserts the author and publisher data stored in a separate table in the database into a dropdown list so that it/they may be selected.

Any and all help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but what are you using to verify that the data is or is not updated? What does `BookInvtryListMgmntGrdView.DataBind();` do, does it reload from the database? Other issues that come to mind but not relevant to your question`WHERE AuthorID = '" + BookIDMgmtTxt.Text.Trim() + "'` is SQL injection, use a parameter instead. `genre` is a comma-separated list, do not do this , instead store them in a separate table foreign-keyed to this one with each genre on a separate row.  Your connection and command objects need `using` blocks to dispose them. ....

Comment: .... `("@PageCount", PageNumTxt.Text.Trim());` you should probably parse it into an `int` first, same goes for any other parameters which are numbers. `AddWithValue` has issues, instead pass the parameter types and lengths explicitly. `if (dbconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)` is unnecessary, it will always be closed as you just created it. `Response.Write("<script>alert(` is somewhat dangerous due to injection risk, and also because it's an odd way to pass info. You should pass a JSON object, and the page itself should generate the alert.

Comment: Aside... [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Consider using the other overloads of `command.Parameters.Add()` that allow you to specify the actual data types and lengths/sizes of the parameters which, among other things, avoids conversion issues with type conversions and plan cache bloat.

Comment: @Charlieface I forgot to mention the GridView that displays the book information. This and the actual database are what I'm using to determine whether or not the information has been updated. Also, I think you just solved my problem, I see now that the WHERE clause was checking AuthorID which exists in an entirely different table. It should instead check the BookID. How silly of me! I made the adjustment and it worked.

Comment: @Charlieface  Even with it working, I am interested in making the improvements you suggested. I'm not very familiar with JSON, how would I go about passing this and generating the alert in the page?

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning. I shall consider this, I had no idea AddWithValue was evil, I thought the real evil was not parametrizing at all.

Comment: There are definitely different levels of evil, and yes obviously not parameterizing is the ultimate Dark Side of the Force, but `AddWithValue` does have problems. JSON: not too familiar with ASP.Net, but I think you would pass it as the `return` value of your controller code. Then the client-side Javascript would deal with alerting the user

Comment: You can select the row that wants to update. I think there is no row to update.
SQL Server does not warn you when there is no row to update